How to use dd with status in busybox?
I use busybox (and buildroot). How to use status? For example
dd if=disk.img of=/dev/sda bs=4M conv=fsync status=progress


In your buildroot's config you should set busybox config file, for example
BR2_PACKAGE_BUSYBOX_CONFIG="$(BR2_EXTERNAL_USERCONFIGTREE_PATH)/board/company/boardname/busybox.config"

And in your busybox.config file use
FEATURE_DD_THIRD_STATUS_LINE=y

